# How to transform and draw image on html canvas?

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

I wanna transform and draw an image on canvas. First I'm transforming an image over canvas through touch gestures and that transformation is handled through css
and controlled by 4 variables `rotation, deltaX, deltaY and scale` where `deltaX` and `deltaY` are positions of center an image. But after finalizing that transformation, I wanna draw that image with same transformations on the canvas. I tried the following but didn't got expected result:

```
img.onload = () => {
  // this.ctx.setTransform(this.transformBlock.scale, 0, 0, this.transformBlock.scale, x, y);
  this.ctx.rotate(this.transformBlock.rotation);
  this.ctx.scale(this.transformBlock.scale, this.transformBlock.scale);
  this.ctx.translate(this.transformBlock.deltaX, this.transformBlock.deltaY);
  this.ctx.drawImage(img, -width / 2, -height / 2);
};
```

Suppose if my transformation is this: `rotation = 90, scale = 2, delX = 180, delY = 320` than my image is 90 deg rotated clockwise with width and height doubled(scale=2) and center of image is at (180px, 320px) (delX, delY). But while drawing on canvas scale is more than 2, most of the image went out of the screen and rotation is not 90 deg. If anybody tell me how to obtain same expected behavior on canvas. It would be great help.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is not as expected? Can you create a working example?

Comment: First I transformed that image over canvas by applying css. Suppose if my transformation is this: rotation = 90 deg, scale = 2, delX = 180, delY = 320 than my image is 90 deg rotated clockwise with width and height doubled(scale=2) and center of image is at (180px, 320px) (delX, delY). But while drawing on canvas scale is more than 2, most of the image went out of screen and rotation is not 90 deg. Can you tell me how to obtain same expected behavior on canvas?

Comment: I can try, but I'll need a **working** example (jsbin, jsfiddle, codepen.. your favorite tool)